# What is a "training point?"

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, statistical-learning

I'm a mathematician studying a book on statistical learning on my own and I'm stuck on a problem, mostly because I don't understand what it's asking. I frequent math SE quite a bit and I know they're not too fond of images pasted from textbooks, so I'll write it out here.

> Consider inputs drawn from a spherical multinormal distribution $X\sim N(0,\mathbf I_p)$. Consider a prediction point $x_0$ drawn from this distribution, and let $a=x_0/\|x_0\|$ be an associated unit vector. Let $z_i=a^Tx_i$ be the projection of each of the training points on this direction. Show that the $z_i$ are distributed $N(0,1)$.

The book is "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman.

Now the way I've been interpreting it is that $x_0$ is the spherical multinormal random variable, and the $x_i$ are arbitrary vectors. However, that can't be right, because if $p=1$ then the variance could be anything.

I don't need a solution to this problem, and in fact I'd rather not see one, I just want to be able to understand the statement of the problem so I can solve it myself.

Comment: Do you know the special properties of the multivariate normal such as the fact that every linear combination of the coordinate variables is a univariate normal?

Comment: @Michael No. I'm an algebraist, but 5 years ago I taught an intro course in probability theory. That distribution wasn't in the textbook, and when I looked it up I didn't read anything about it except the explicit formula for the density function. That's good to know.

Comment: Also a spherical normal has all its component variables independent. The fact that X is distributed as a multivariate normal with covariance matrix a pxp identity matrix means that all component normals have their variance equal to the the corresponding diagonal element of the identity matrix.

Comment: The multivariate normal is 2 dimensional or higher. We usually don't consider the univariate case t be a special case of the multivariate normal.  I hope this is will eliminate your confusion and you can see now how to solve your problem.

Comment: I think here "training points" is the same as "inputs". So it is $x_0$ which is an arbitrary vector, and each $x_i\sim\mathrm{N}_{0,I_p}$? I am not sure of your book, but commonly in ML the "training data" is considered to be an [tag:iid] sample from some "data generating distribution" (e.g. see [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html)).

Comment: By the way, we appreciate you taking the time to write out the textbook question! (you can use ">" for a block quote, fyi). It could be good in cases like this to provide the book's name, as some books/authors can use idiosyncratic terminology! (I myself actually try to give a linked cite if possible, e.g. via Google Books; or at least Google Scholar ... but that is certainly not required.)

Answer (score 0):

I think GeoMatt22's suggestion was right. The "prediction point" and the "training points" are independent and identically distributed. I should be able to solve the problem now.